# How do i unscrew this bolt to take apart the bed frame

Tags: bedroom

I have this couple bed that need to disassemble but have no idea how to unscrew this bolt in the pictures. I have never seen anything like this in my life.

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A pin is used through the head to unscrew. A drill bit or Allen key as large as will fit will provide enough torque to get them out unless someone used pliers on them but I don’t see any damage.

Many had decorative handles on them that after being tightened one times too many and broke.

Comment: A thin nail set is a great tool for this as well.  Fits tight in the hole and easy to grip.

Comment: Yes, and if you look closely it seems there is a slight circular scratch that was cause by the now-missing decorative handle.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good way to keep the kids* from taking it apart!

I've never seen one like that, either. I'd presume that something thin like a hex-key would fit through the hole on the knob on the outside to turn it while an adjustable wrench would hold the square nut on the inside.

*My then 2-year-old started removing screws from the under side of my desk. Because God's got a sense of humor, his 2 year old did the same. :)